# how to enable and disable a floating action button if list is empty?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using FloatingActionButton and as you can see I want it to appear if the size of a List is greater than 0 and disappear when it is 0
I have a view that adds items to that List
but unfortunately the script is only executed once and it does not listen to the size of the List at all times

````
class EventDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Event event;
  const EventDetailsPage({Key key, this.event}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Provider<Event>.value(
        value: event,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            EventDetailsBackground(),
            EventDetailsContent(),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: new Visibility( 
        visible: qrList.length>0?true:false,
        child: new FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: (){
            qrList = qrList.toSet().toList();
          },
          label: Text('GENERAR QR',),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        ),     
      ),

    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Try with StatefullWidget instance of StatelessWidget ,

Comment: Is there some point in your code where you *remove* elements from the list?

Comment: yes, but in another view is where I add or remove elements from my list

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code please.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of thing you should use some reactive statate manage, take a look at getx pakage (https://pub.dev/packages/get#reactive-state-manager) it has some good ways to to observe changes on a list for situations like that.

you could reach this with changeNotifier too, just put your list in a class that extends it and put you floating button in a Consumer widget, and everytime your list add/remove a value you trigger notifyListeners(). For this aproach user Provider package (https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

an example using getx package:

```dart
class MyList extends GetxController {
 final qrList = List<Foo>().obs;
}

// this way you can insert this in the app, remember to put this above all the widgets that use this list
Get.put<MyList>(MyList());

floatingActionButton: Obx(() {
      final qrList = Get.find<MyList>().qrlist;

      return Visibility(
          visible: qrList.length > 0 ? true : false,
          child: new FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              qrList = qrList.toSet().toList();
            },
            label: Text(
              'GENERAR QR',
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ));
    });,
```

with this any change in the list the button will update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and let me know if it works,

```
floatingActionButton: qrList.length>0 ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: (){
        qrList = qrList.toSet().toList();
      },
      label: Text('GENERAR QR',),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
  ): SizedBox.shrink(),
```

Comment: it works, but the script "qrList.length> 0" is only executed once and does not listen if I change the length of the list

Comment: you will need to use setState to update the value of qrList.length in the stateful widget where you are calling this particular stateless widget.

Comment: I was able to add setState, the actions of adding or eliminating values ​​in the list I have it in another file and I cannot command that they change the state false or true with the setState